# Aurora Master can't connect to MySQL master during replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds, amazon-aurora

I am migrating from RDS MYSQL 5.7 to Aurora 5.6. Using the steps mentioned here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/migrate-mysql-aurora/

I'm at a stage where I login into my aurora master instance and set its master as my MySQL source instance. After I execute CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master, I see that the slave status is **"Connecting to Master"** and fails with error 2003. Source MySQL and Aurora are in same VPC, subnet.

```
           Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
         Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
```

The logs have following error

```
2017-04-30 20:00:00 12151 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master X.com3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1, Error_code: 2003
```

pointers?

Comment: Verify that the security group on MySQL allows connections to port 3306 *from* Aurora? `SET GLOBAL @@LOG_WARNINGS = 2` on MySQL and check the MySQL error logs for any connections being attempted?  Check the Aurora error log in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Very generic error, but we faced a similar issue and solved it by providing the IP address.

> Use the Master or Source database name using the IP address, instead
>   of end points.

Answer (score 0):

just add below inbound rule inside RDS security group(sg)

MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306 custom source: same security group name(sg)